# Dynamically generate optgroup in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

```
<div style="text-align: center">
<select  id="list" name="select-restaurants" data-native-menu="false" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="choose" data-placeholder="true">Members</option>
         <optgroup label=" " id = "aac">
         <option value="a">abc</option>
         <option value="b">def</option>
         <option value="c">ghi</option>
         <option value="d">jkl</option>
         <option value="e">mno</option>
         <option value="f">pqr</option>

         </optgroup>
</select>
</div>
```

I want to generate this dynamically, I am trying below code but this not works for me.

```
$("#list").empty();//Clear options if there are any already existing ones.

for( i=1; i<= positions; i++ )
{

    $("#list").append($("<option value="+i+">"+ i+"</option>") );

}
```

Kindly help if somebody knew this.

Comment: If you could put up a fiddle, I would be able to solve it.

Comment: @raghaw I am new in this can you please explain what is fiddle?

Comment: Have a look at jsfiddle.com. Basically to set up a demo of your problem.

Comment: I have check this, but this is not showing the data which i want to display at run time. This only showing the data that is hard coded in html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can generate it dynamically.

Here's an example I have created some time ago: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/rh7Nq/

Main thing is to use:

```
$("#selectID").selectmenu('refresh', true);
```

After select is dynamically populated.

Comment: as when I use the code that i have post no changes occur and  the same values shown as which is hardcoded in html

Comment: Are we looking at the same example? If you look carefully you will see select box is empty, elements are added dynamically through java script at the bottom. Top left screen of jsFiddle is HTML, bottom left screen is a javascript code, top right screen is a CSS window and bottom right screen is an output. So values are not hardcoded into HTML.

Comment: I am getting this error, Uncaught cannot call methods on selectmenu prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'

Comment: In that case use first $("#selectID").selectmenu(); to initialize a select, then use $("#selectID").selectmenu('refresh', true); to restyle it.

Comment: Error removed. Now I am get an empty list.

Comment: In which page event are you populating a select box?